# How to create a ClaimsPrincipal that has Identity.Authenticated set to true?

Tags: claims-based-identity

I have the following method:

```
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (Composite.C1Console.Security.UserValidationFacade.IsLoggedIn())
                SetPrincipal(request, new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator") },)));
            var test = request.GetClaimsPrincipal();
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
```

my problem is that if i inspect the `test.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is has not been set to true. This is just some test code to figure out how. What am I missing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set an authentication type in the ClaimsIdentity ctor.

Comment: figured it out 5min ago :D Thanks

Answer (score 24):

You need to specify a `ClaimsIdentity` instance to the `ClaimsPrincipal` constructor that specifies a `authenticationType` such as "Basic". Claims can be `null`.

```cs
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(null, "Basic"));
var isAuthenticated = principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated; // true
```

Answer (score 4):

```
        if (Composite.C1Console.Security.UserValidationFacade.IsLoggedIn())
            SetPrincipal(request, new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] { 
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"), 
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, UserValidationFacade.GetUsername())}, "Basic")));
        var test = request.GetClaimsPrincipal();
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```